# contentEditable: ввод основным стилем на стыке ситлей

Tags: html

```
<div contentEditable="true">
  <b>Bold</b>normal<i>italic</i>
</div>
```

- Если мы попытаемся что-то ввести перед перед `Bold`, то введёные символы будут жирными. Однако, если мы введём что-то перед перед буквой `i` слова `italic`, введённые символы не будут курсивными.
- Если мы введём что-то после `Bold` или `italic`, то символы будут иметь соответствующий вид.

Разграничение стилей в WYSIWYG-редактораз - отдельная нетривиальная задача, которая нормально не решена даже в Word. В данном вопросе достаточно добиться того, чтобы перед словом с другим стилем и после него ввод осуществлялся основным стилем (то есть НЕ жирный и НЕ курсивный). Другими словами, в данном примере достаточно того, чтобы вводимые символы были не курсивные и не жирные, если мы введёный символ:

- Находится до или после слова `Bold`
- Между словами `Bold` и `italic`
- после слова `italic`

Какие подходы к решению данной задачи можно предложить? Из сторонних библиотек допускается только `jQuery`.